# XCode debugger not helping find device-only issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, gdb

So, I have an iOS tabbed app (live and free in the store [http://itunes.com/apps/iphoundyou]). One tab is a grouped tableview, with the number of groups (1 or 2) dependent on some JSON that a web service returns. The JSON is valid and straightforward. Handling it seems to be easy, and, when run in the simulator, **behaves as expected**. However, I just found that when run on the device, if the two section reaction is needed...it crashes.

"ok" I thought "I'll just hook up my device, launch the debugger, replicate the crash, and figure out where I have a bug"

However, when I did that, I get the most unhelpful response I could expect:

[image: debugger not debugging]

So, given that it works in the simulator, is there any suggestions as to how else to track down the flaw? The code for the tableview is nothing special, along the lines of "if this JSON key exists, number of sections=2...with the number of rows of that section equal to the number of items in another array within the JSON"

Another note: I recently started seeing a dozen or so of these when launching an app: 
`unable to read unknown load command 0x25`
`unable to read unknown load command 0x26`

Thanks so much.

Comment: Something is messed up with your stack. That is very hard to trace. Try to set a breakpoint and go line by line.

Comment: Are you basing that on the debugger ??'s or the unknown load commands? Thanks for your help

Comment: A stack corruption has few common symptoms two of which are the debugger has no clue what function is called and the second is illegal instructions ( = unknown load command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it turned out that it was just my own error: I'd updated my device OS but didn't have that SDK (I was behind in updating XCode)